# Converting Unix timestamp in Google App scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, unix-timestamp

I am new to Google App Script and am currently working on a project to help myself get familiar with it. My project has a part where I have to convert Unix Timestamp objects in nested JSON to human-readable time. As I don't know about converting timestamps in Google App scripts, I looked into the documentation and found "Utilities.formatDate()".

I tried using it on an example timestamp to see how it works and if it can be used for my needs. So I took a timestamp from the data and tried converting it with this code.

```
 function blah () {
  var tim = "1572401067";
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(tim, "GMT+5:30", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  Logger.log(formattedDate);
  }
```

It ends with an error saying:

```
Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string). (line 3, file "Code")Dismiss
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I turn a UNIX timestamp into a Google Sheets date value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391562/how-can-i-turn-a-unix-timestamp-into-a-google-sheets-date-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error message correctly describes, there is no such function as `formatDate(string,string,string)`. The [`formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) function that exists in GAS  takes three parameters, where the first one is a `Date`, and the second and third ones are `string`'s. A correction of your code could look like the following:

```js
function blah() {
  var tim = 1572401067;
  var date = new Date(tim*1000);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+5:30", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had completely forgotten about it in the excitement that's been going on lately.